# How to correctly use variable in java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've ran into a strange situation, when I try to use a member variable in the thread I create, it doesn't return the correct value, below is a snippet of my code

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                //System.out.println(printQueue.isEmpty());
                while ((currentOrder = printQueue.poll())!= null) {
                    printall();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

`printQueue` is a queue I defined, the result is different when I try to push a value into the queue.
when I uncomment the print line,this `currentOrder` will return a non-null variable,but if I comment that line, `currentOrder` will always return null.
   How does it happen and what am I supposed to do to resolve it?

Comment: What type is printQueue? is it thread safe?

Comment: `Queue<PrintInfo> printQueue = new LinkedList<PrintInfo>()` and PrintInfo is a class I defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinkedList` class isn't designed for use in multithreaded applications. Individual threads can cache the state of the `LinkedList` in their local memories, which can cause the state to appear inconsistent.

You should probably use a [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead and see if that solves the problem. This is probably an issue with the threads not seeing updates, but writing to `System.out` is causing the thread-local memory to be flushed.

If you want to learn a bit more about what's going on here you might want to refer to this question:

[What does flushing thread local memory to global memory mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2495654/1427124)